# Multiple googleMaps in one page with non sequential ID's

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have this code to create multiple google maps into one page.

I'm loading the script and runing initMap() as a callback.
It works very good but only if the div's that will contain the maps has a sequential ID's, for example in this case:

```
<div id="mapSection1"></div>
<div id="mapSection2"></div>
```

JS code:

```
var coords = [
    {lat: 49.18589, lng: -2.19917, zoom: 10},
    {lat: 101.1986, lng: -50.2445, zoom: 12}
];
var markers = [];
var maps = [];

function initMap() {
    for(var i = 0, length = coords.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        var point = coords[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

        /**********Div's are called in this line*********/
        maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapSection' + (i + 1)), {
            zoom: point.zoom,
            center: latlng
        });

        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: maps[i]
        });
    }
}
```

Everything is all right but in my case the ID's are not sequential, for example:

```
<div id="mapNort"></div>
<div id="mapSouth"></div>
```

The question is, how can I include this ID's into the loop that is writing the code to display the maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to give the `<div>`'s a class, then use `getElementsByClassName` to get references to them (BTW, `lat: 101.1986` is not a valid latitude).

```
var coords = [
    {lat: 49.18589, lng: -2.19917, zoom: 10},
    {lat: 51.1986, lng: -50.2445, zoom: 12}
];
var markers = [];
var maps = [];

function initMap() {
    for(var i = 0, length = coords.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        var point = coords[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

        /**********Div's are called in this line*********/
        maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[i], {
            zoom: point.zoom,
            center: latlng
        });

        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: maps[i]
        });
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ga1xwyz9/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var coords = [{
    lat: 49.18589,
    lng: -2.19917,
    zoom: 10
  },
  {
    lat: 51.1986,
    lng: -50.2445,
    zoom: 12
  }
];
var markers = [];
var maps = [];

function initMap() {
  for (var i = 0, length = coords.length; i < length; i++) {
    var point = coords[i];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    /**********Div's are called in this line*********/
    maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[i], {
      zoom: point.zoom,
      center: latlng
    });

    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: maps[i]
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#mapNorth {
  height: 49%;
  width: 100%;
  float: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#mapSouth {
  height: 49%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapNorth" class="map"></div>
<div id="mapSouth" class="map"></div>
```